# c++ harmonic value from time increment

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have a counter in milliseconds that always increases during normal program execution.  I wish to mathematically convert this counter into a harmonic value:

```
float getHarmonicTime(int currentTime, int periodInMilliSeconds)
{
    // Some cool algorithm here
}
```

This function would return a floating point value between -1 and 1 over the course of the given period like so:

```
-1...-0.5...0...0.5...1...0.5...0...-0.5...-1
```

How would I do this algorithmically as well as efficiently in c/c++?

Thanks!

Comment: what is harmonic value?  harmonic mean? harmonic number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you're probably looking for is `sin( 2 * M_PI * currentTime / period )`.